# Dropbox API V2 authenticateWithCordova not working as expected

Tags: javascript, cordova, dropbox

I have Cordova application in which have implemented the Dropbox functionality using javascript SDK. I use authenticateWithCordova method to authenticate the users.

The authenticateWithCordova method works fine for the first time and successfully returns the access token. The access token can then be subsequently used for other operations such as upload, download etc.

I am using as below URI as redirect URI,

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver
```

When I call authenticateWithCordova method for the second time it shows a login screen for second and returns to the app. I want the users to be able to use different Dropbox accounts.Need Some Help!

Answer (score 0):

If the user signed in to the browser has already authorized your app, they may be automatically redirected back to your app instead of having to provide explicit authorization again.

The API offers the ability to control that using the `force_reapprove` parameter on [/oauth2/authorize](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize), though that's unfortunately not currently implemented in the API v2 JavaScript SDK itself, e.g., for the `authenticateWithCordova` method. We'll consider it a feature request for implementing that in the SDK, but I can't promise if/when that would be done.

If you need a workaround, you can direct the user to https://www.dropbox.com/logout to log out of the account first.

Comment: If I direct the user to https://www.dropbox.com/logout and if the user logs in again it will show the user his Dropbox account. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the user goes to dropbox.com/logout , that will log them out of the Dropbox web site. (Note that this is not connected to any pre-existing API access token.) If the user logs in to the web site again, they should see their account on the web site again. What exactly isn't working as expected?